# android checkbox to string and verification

Tags: android, validation, text, checkbox

i have 12 check boxes in my layout.
i need to make sure the user selects only 5, then press the save button.
when he presses the save - the check boxes he selected should be shown in a text view and all other check boxes turn grey(unclickable). if he chooses more than 5 - toast tells him he must choose only 5.
1st problem i have is how to turn the other check boxes grey.
2nd problem is when he deselects 1 check box the size of my hashmap is still more than five.

here is code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    Map<String, String> states = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CheckBox checkboxMovies = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsMovies);
        checkboxMovies.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxAnimals = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsAnimals);
        checkboxAnimals.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxShopping = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsShopping);
        checkboxShopping.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxBooks = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsBooks);
        checkboxBooks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxRestaurants = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsRestaurants);
        checkboxRestaurants.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxComputers = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsComputers);
        checkboxComputers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxTV = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsTV);
        checkboxTV.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxPubs = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsPubs);
        checkboxPubs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxDancing = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsDancing);
        checkboxDancing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxMusic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsMusic);
        checkboxMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxCoffe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsCoffe);
        checkboxCoffe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        CheckBox checkboxOther = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkInterestsOther);
        checkboxOther.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            states.put(String.valueOf(buttonView.getId()), buttonView.getText().toString());
        } else {
            states.remove(buttonView.getId());
        }
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (states.size() == 5) {
                    List<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(states.values());
                    TextView chkEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chkEditText);
                    chkEditText.setText(selectedStrings.toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only 5 are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

can anyone plz help me?

Comment: I suggest to use the ArrayList to save the selected checkbox string and you can choose what to show open or gray by checking the array contains, and you can delete the string from array if he uncheck the checkbox

Comment: In order to uncheck all of the checkboxes, you'll need them in a list. For the second problem. Change your remove method to take the String value of the id, or modify your map to be <Integer,String>

Comment: modified the map to <Integer, String) - it worked! thank you,, can you show me how to make a list of check boxes and to that first problem>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your map to be `<Integer,String>` (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621895/android-checkbox-to-string-and-verification/35757821#comment58926304_35621895) by [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007))  worked...

Thank you